# function to add shortcode

Tags: wordpress, function, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I want to create a function to add a Wordpress shortcode but only in the page "news-blog" after the header in the content section.

This is my code, which is not working:

```
add_action ('__after_header' , 'add_content_after_header', 0);
  function add_content_after_header() {
  echo do_shortcode( '[ivory-search id="3668" title="Search"]' );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `header.php` have properly included and wp_head is called in it. Because this hook use this function to populate whatever you are adding in Hook's function.

Thanks